# Understanding Python Attributes and Methods

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python and am a bit confused about a script I am playing with.  I am using Python to launch scapy.  There are some conditional statements that test for certain values.  My confusion is centered around how the values are checked.  I hope I am using the terms attributes and methods appropriately.  I am still trying to figure out the builtin features vs. what is included with scapy.  I've been using Powershell mainly for the last few years so its hard to switch gears :)

```
tcp_connect_scan_resp = sr1(IP(dst=dst_ip)/TCP(sport=src_port,dport=dst_port,flags="S"),timeout=10)
if(str(type(tcp_connect_scan_resp))=="<type 'NoneType'>"):
    Print "Closed"
elif(tcp_connect_scan_resp.haslayer(TCP)):
    if(tcp_connect_scan_resp.getlayer(TCP).flags == 0x12):
```

The first conditional statement appears to be check for the attribute 'type'.  Why would they use the Python built-in `str()` and `type()` functions in this case? If I just use `type()` it pulls the same value.

For the second and third conditional statements appear to be using methods built into scapy.  What is the logic for including the brackets () on the outside of the statements? Again if I run them manually, I get the proper value.

Comment: The answers to all of your questions, unfortunately, is that this is extremely unidiomatic and unPythonic code. I can't imagine why anyone would write this.

Comment: By the way, do you mean `scapy` or `scrapy`?

Comment: Consider to put your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for a comprehensive feedback on Pythonic style.

Comment: What do you mean by *`What is the logic for including the brackets () on the outside of the statements?`*

Comment: Yes I meant scapy.  Regarding the brackets:  why use elif(tcp_connect_scan_resp.haslayer(TCP)): vs. elif tcp_connect_scan_resp.haslayer(TCP):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second statement, the parantheses around the expression of an `if` statement, is simply unnecessary and bad style.

The first statement warrants a more detailed explanation:

```
if(str(type(tcp_connect_scan_resp))=="<type 'NoneType'>"):
```

This checks if the string representation of the type that `tcp_connect_scan_resp` is of is equal to "". This is a bad form of type checking, used in a bad way. There are situations where type checking may be necessary, but generally you should try to avoid it in Python (see [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)). If you must, use [`isinstance()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance).

In the case of the Python builtin type `None`, the idiomatic way is to just write

```
if foo is None
```

Now, the reason you got the "same result" by using `type()` yourself, is that if you enter someting in an interactive Python shell, the interpreter *represents* the value for you (by calling [`__repr__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr)). Except for basic types that have literal notations, like integers, strings, or sequences, the representation of an object isn't necessarlily the same as its value (or what you would type in to recreate that same object).

So, when you do

```
>>> foo = type(42)
>>> foo
<type 'int'>
```

the interpreter prints `'<type 'int'>'`, but the result of the call is actualy `int`, the built-in type for integers:

```
>>> type(42) == int
True
>>> type(42) == "<type 'int'>"
False
```

Also, consider this:

Libraries or tools written to help with a specific field of expertise are often written by experts in those fields - not necessarily experts in Python. In my opinion, you often see this in scientific libraries ([`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/) and [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) for example). This doesn't mean they're bad libraries, but they often aren't a good inspiration for Pythonic style.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Part of your explanation is fuzzy, but that is because I am relatively new to Python.

Answer (score 0):

Never check a type by comparing `str(type(obj)) == 'ClassName'`.

You should use `isinstance(obj, Class)`, or for None you just write `if obj is None`.